# Кодировка MySQL Linux

Tags: java, mysql, linux, hibernate

Есть приложение на Java, для работы с MySQL используется Hibernate.
Приложение отправляет String запрос на русском в БД и получает String ответ. 
На Win10 все работает.

Перенес на Linux. Теперь когда я отправляю String запрос состоящий только из цифр
 все ок. Но когда запрос состоит из букв и цифр, база его не понимает.

- В базе стоит UTF-8
- В IDEA стоит UTF-8
- В hibernate стоит UTF-8
- Выводил в консоль запрос, который идет в базу, все ок. Все символы те что надо.

Понятное дело что причина в кодировке, linux при обработке запроса отправлят в базу какую-то другую кодировку...как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть решение этой проблемы в другой теме.

В конфигурации Hibernate на писать

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quotesdb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
```

На конце utf8, а не UTF-8